# Spring Data JpaRepository saveAndFlush within @Transactional not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Currently I am facing a problem with Spring-Data/Hibernate that I will introduce briefly.

I am working on some simple Reporting functionality, that fetches Entities from a single table as Stream. This is working fine, but has to happen within a longer running Transaction, because the Connection to the Database needs to stay open. Within this transaction I want to constantly update a ReportEntity, which tracks the status and the progress of the process. Code looks basically like this:

```
    @Async
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public void process(Long reportId, SearchCriteria searchCriteriaTo) {

        ReportEntity report = reportRepository.findById(reportId).get();
        report.setStatus(ReportGenerationStatus.START);
        reportRepository.saveAndFlush(report);

        Stream<RawDataEntity> rawDataEntityStream = this.rawDataRepository
            .findAllFiltered(...);

        report.setStatus(ReportGenerationStatus.GENERATING_REPORT);
        report.setProgress(50);
        reportRepository.saveAndFlush(report);

        ...

        rawDataEntityStream.forEach(() -> DoSomething())

        ...

        report.setStatus(ReportGenerationStatus.FINISHED);
        report.setProgress(100);
    }
```

My problem is, that from my understanding saveAndFlush should write the intermediate steps of The ReportEntity into the database, but it does not. I am using a Posgres DB and verified this with PGAdmin and also I wrote a polling client that constantly fetches the ReportEntity.

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ReportEto getReportByKey(UUID key) {
        // entityManager.clear();
        ReportEntity reportEntity = this.reportRepository.findByKey(key);
        return getBeanMapper().map(reportEntity, ReportEto.class);
    }
```

But the status "GENERATING_REPORT" does not get written to the DB. Only after the final commit the status is updated to FINSIH. I tried to set the isolation level to "READ_UNCOMMITTED", but this also does not have an effect. The Hibernate Debug Logs however suggest, that a Update is triggered:

```
o.h.e.i.DefaultMergeEventListener        : EntityCopyObserver strategy: disallow
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.capgemini.cusmesonlinereporting.reportmanagement.dataaccess.api.ReportEntity{downloadLink=null, externalUserId=MMUSTER, modificationCounter=0, creationTimestamp=2020-03-26T07:21:03.421700Z, name=2018-1-1_2020-3-23, progress=0, id=1000019, key=ecb0955f-b838-4f30-ac1f-dc94763ac810, status=GENERATING_REPORT}
org.hibernate.SQL                        : update Report set modificationCounter=?, creationTimestamp=?, downloadLink=?, externalUserId=?, key=?, name=?, progress=?, status=? where id=? and modificationCounter=?
Hibernate: update Report set modificationCounter=?, creationTimestamp=?, downloadLink=?, externalUserId=?, key=?, name=?, progress=?, status=? where id=? and modificationCounter=?
```

I could go ahead and make all the updates to the ReportEntity in a nested Transaction with a "REQUIRE_NEW" Transaction, but I dont want to run into potential DeadLocks because of the long running Transaction that might get executed multiple times in parallel.
So my questions are:

1. Why does saveAndFlush not work in this case ?
2. are there any workarounds that do not involve creating nested transactions?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Flush will send the pending changes to the DB BUT only within the current transaction. It will NOT commit changes. The only way to persist stuff in the datbase is with a transaction, so you need either more transaction or need a better way of solving your processing.

Comment: Okay, but I thought "Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED" should address exactly this problem. From Spring docs: "This level allows a row changed by one transaction to be read by another transaction before any changes in that row have been committed"

Comment: Again your understanding is wrong. Nothing is persisted UNTILL a transaction is committed. Even wit that isolation level if something goes wrong the changes will be rolled back (and others will have read dirty data aka dirte-read!). So your only solution is additional transactions. Also your processing seems flawed as you are reading everything in memory at once, don't, you have a single large transaction for batch processing (don't or processing in chunks and flush/clear). Doing that will quite seriously improve your performance. Especially when using and ORM.

Comment: essentially I am trying to stream data with the JpaRepository to avoid having all In-Memory, using the approach that is discribed here https://www.geekyhacker.com/2019/03/26/high-performance-data-fetching-using-spring-data-jpa-stream/. Currently I am evaluating if this works for me. Comming back to the transactions: I got that nothing is persited until commit, but how can dirty reads from other transactions happen than in the first place? Need both transactions a reference to the same Entity Object?

Comment: Because others are allowed to read uncommitted data. Say you change the balance from the bankaccount to 200 (but haven't committed yet), some other transactions reads this value, and increases that with another 100. However in the meantime you rolled back the balance to 100. Hence he has read dirty data. Also **just** streaming won't help that much, the main issue here is the large transaction that holds all changes. Each time you do a select or operation a dirty check is done, which will increase signifactnly with each entry that has changed. That is why you should regularly flush and clear.